# overflow:hidden works for body but not for wrapper

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to assign overflow:hidden to the wrapper but it is ignored. It works however, if I assign it to body. Does anyone have an idea how to make it work for the wrapper?

The HTML...

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Overflow Test</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <header></header>

    <main>

        <div id="content"></div>

    </main>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The CSS...

```
html    {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
min-height: 100%;
    }
body    {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
min-height: 100%;
    }
#wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
}
header  {
position: fixed;
top: 0xp;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #d20000;
}
main    {   
width: 100%;
height: auto;
    }
#content {
width: 100%;
height: 3000px;
background-color: #ffdd00;
}
```

Help would me much appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate what you try to accomplish? Is it to remove the scrollbar from the page?

Comment: Sure... There's a lot of text on the page and people can scroll down to read all of it - which is fine. But as soon as the off-canvas menu I previously mentioned comes out, I want to disable scrolling for the text in the background while keeping the option to scroll the off-canvas menu if necessary. That's why I can't just assign overflow:hidden to html or body where it would work flawlessly...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work by putting my wrapper inside another div with position:absolute and top and bottom set to 0. I took inspiration from this thread http://goo.gl/U3OQQV

Here's the new fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/aaandreas/esLcw3md/2/ Thanks for your effort turbopipp, I appreciate it!

Here's the updated HTML...

```
<body>

<div id="prewrapper">

<div id="wrapper">

    <header></header>

    <main>

        <div id="content"></div>

    </main>

</div>

</div>
```

And the updated CSS...

```
html    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        }
body    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        }
#prewrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0xp;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #d20000;
}
main    {   
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
        }
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3000px;
    background-color: #ffdd00;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome :) Glad you found a solution, I struggled a bit to understand your end game here. :) Pos:absolute with top/bottom:0 effectivly sets the height to the screens height, thats why overflow: hidden works now, it has limits. :) You could also add `position:absolute;top:50px;` to your div#content if you want to avoid the text hiding behind your header.

Answer (score 2):

Typo, change `<div id="#wrapper">` to `<div id="wrapper">`

Update: I change the #content height to 100px, and created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/8f33z8yj/) to test if it works, and it seems it does. You must have removed much of your code in the example you provided, perhaps something else is causing the problem? Or is it the #content height 3000px that is the problem?

Update2: I think you want to activate/deactivate scrolling on body based on the status of your menu. I created [this little fiddle with jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/ovm7tvk3/) to show you how you can toggle a class on body. Just tie the listener to your menubutton instead of the whole wrapper element like I did, and watch the class `.overflow` getting added/removed to `body`. I hope this was the answer you where looking for?

Comment: Updated my answer, it should work. Perhaps you could reproduce the error in that/another fiddle, and post it back to me?

Comment: Thanks turbopipp, the only thing I removed from my code is an off-canvas menu which resides outside the wrapper div. My real content is a lot of text which is not relevant to the problem. So I set the content height to 3000px to simulate this...

Comment: Aha, then that was your problem. Use some "Lorem Ipsum" text instead and the `overflow: hidden` will work. The way it works is that it removes text outside the container limits, therefore if you enlarge the container limits to test it, it will never work. Instead reduce the container limits to test it like I did in the example. If you feel I solved your question, please remember to mark my answer as accepted. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I would love to mark your answer as accepted. The only problem is I set my content height to auto, used "Lorem Ipsum" text and it still doesn't work...

Comment: The content height need to be limited before `overflow: hidden` will work. `height: auto` won't work. And `height: 100%` will only work if the parent container height is limited. Could you [reproduce the error here](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/8f33z8yj/) if it doesn't work, and link back to me?

Comment: You could therefore make the `#wrapper` height fixed, like 100px, and then let `<main>` and `#content` be `height:auto` [(See demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/ftfeubhp/)

Comment: Sure, here it is... https://jsfiddle.net/aaandreas/8f33z8yj/8/ Assigning overflow:hidden to html or body works perfectly. But when it is assigned to the wrapper it is completely ignored... I don't think limiting the height is a good idea when the content is text, the height of which is unpredictable. So I was hoping for another solution...

Comment: I am not sure anymore what you try to accomplish. Body/HTML has a scrollbar, while your wrapper does not. overflow: hidden hides the scrollbar. For the wrapper to get a scrollbar to hide, the wrapper needs a limited height. Then you can use overflow: hidden. If you want your wrapper to have auto height, why do you want to hide its non-existing scrollbar?